# Como imprimir um arquivo txt em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como imprimir um arquivo txt em Python?

Não estou me referindo a print e sim a imprimir na impressora.

Agradeço (:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python é uma linguagem de programação genérica - e não tem relação a como o sistema operacional disponiliza os seus periféricos ou APIs de impressão para uso de programas.

No Windows, tipicamente essas chamadas envolvem o uso do win32api - um módulo do Python com extensões que permitem o acesso direto à API32 do Windows - 
aqui tem [uma página com exemplo de como fazer isso,](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) passando direto o nome do arquivo que se deseja imprimir. Para instalar o Win32API, baixe a versão correspondnte ao seu Python do último build (número maior) aqui:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/

Isso vale para scripts "stand-alone". Se você está usando uma biblioteca multiplataforma para aplicações Desktop como GTK+ ou Qt - essa biblioteca em geral tem chamadas proprias para impressão - elas em geral vão incluir chamadas para abrir o diálogo de impressão, que exibe as impressoras disponíveis, e a montar seu documento para impressão em memória,e depois passar para a api de impressão - nos dois casos vale a pena olhar a
documentação em C, por que infelizmetne a documentação em Python é um pouco falha - as chamadas em Python são mapeadas de maneira mais ou menos direta se você já está programando em um dos dois frameworks:

Para Qt4  você pode ver aqui: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/printing.html
E para gtk+ : 
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/printing.html - (parece que que a composição do documento que você prcisa fazer é ainda mais complexa).

---

Em MacOSX /Linux, se você não está usando GTK+ ou Qt,  você vai ter que renderizar seu documento para postscript
(o Tkinter pode fazer isso direto, se sua aplicação for com o mesmo - senão, minha sugestão é instalar e usar o "enscript" como programa externo para compor o seu texto como um arquvo postscript "bobo" para impressão.

Dpois disso você pode disparar a impressão usando o CUPS - a sugestão é usar o PyCUPS para poder escolher a impressora programaticamente e enviar seu arquivo postscript como um job para a mesma.

---

Como você pode ver, pode não ser uma tarefa fácil - principalmente se você quiser uma solução multiplataforma. 
Um hack interessante que deixo anotado aqui, e talvez seja o mais interessante para você é: 
use o Python para abrir o arquivo no Browser padrão do sistema - e peça para o usuário usar o menu de impressão do browser para a impressão.  A vanatem desse método é que é fácil compor o documento com HTML e CSS em vez de texto puro, e ter uma impressão bem bonita:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("file:///<caminho>/<para>/<seu-arquivo>")
print ("O documento a ser impresso foi aberto no navegador - use
as opções de impressão do mesmo")
```

---

PS. se for uma impressora matricial, que aceite texto direto, sem passar por drivers, em qualquer sistema, é só copiar o arquivo para o arqivo-dispositivo da impressora:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(<seu_arquivo>, "prn")  # "prn" no windows - no linux, tipicamente /dev/lp0
```

---

**update** uma outra forma de criar uma saída de texto decente, que você pode exportar para postscript, e então copiar esse postscript para o dispositivo de impressora (Mac, linux) ou usar o ghostscript para passar do Postscript para uma impressora específica que não suporte postscript diretamente é usar o Cairo (PyCairo)  - essa biblioteca tem várias funcionalidades para tratamento de texto e de caractéres - suportando diferentes fontes, cores, etc....

Infelizmente a coisa ainda é complicadinha - provavelmente você teria que codificar a lógica da quebra de linhas manualmente. Usar Cairo faria o papel do programa externo "enscript" que citei acima, mas te dando todo o controle da renderização.

Comment: Então - o problema todo é que - de fato não é simples. Os exemplos simples são os que estão aí.  :-)  - depois de responder ainda fui dar uma olhada no Tkinter: ele não tem um método prático de gerar postscript a partir de texto num widget Text (mas pode faze-lo de um Canvas) - a implicação direta disso é que sem usar algo como enscripten, ou um gerador de PDF como o ReportLab, para uma impressora moderna, o seu código tem que é que tem que criar o layout de saída do texto.

Comment: Fui até olhar, com uma calma razoável, no Pypi se havia algum pacote que abstraia a questão de impressoras e/ou a geração de texto com layout  (e fosse multiplataforma - mas isso seria opicional)- mas não tem.

Comment: Resposta relacionada - com mais alguns exemplos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/280033/automatizar-impress%C3%A3o-de-arquivos-dentro-de-uma-pasta/280043#280043

Answer (score 3):

Até hoje preferi gerar em PDF usando o Reportlab. Não é a solução mais direta, mas pelo menos é a mais compatível. Se quiser automatizar a impressão, basta invocar o Adobe Reader pela linha de comando, no caso do Windows. Se eu estiver somente em ambiente *nix, ficaria só com PS mesmo.

Comment: Pois é - mas dada minha resposta, pode mesmo ser um dos melhores jeitos. (eu particularemente gostei do hack com "webbrowser" - talvez dê para colocar um javascript que acione a impressão, junto com o texto)