# Automatizar impressão de arquivos dentro de uma pasta

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, impressão

Preciso fazer com que qualquer arquivo que esteja na pasta, exemplo `c://imprimir` vá sendo impresso automaticamente, *verifica se tem algo e manda para impressora padrão*.

Estive pesquisando em Python porém consegui basicamente acessar a pasta e listar e contar cada arquivo que esta dentro 1 a 1.

```
import os
import time
import glob

try:
    #Passa o caminho onde estão os arquivos pdf
    loc = input('Localizacao: ')

    #localizar pasta
    floc = loc.replace("'\'","'/'")

    #nav até caminho informado
    os.chdir(floc)

    x = 0

    #Verifica todos arquivos .pdf que tem na pasta
    for file in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
        if(file != ''):
            os.startfile(file, 'print')
            print('Imprimindo arquivo.. ' + str(file))
            x += 1
            time.sleep(2)

    print('Arquivos impressos: ' + str(x))

except Exception as a:
    print(a)
```

@Resultado:

```
=============== RESTART: C:/Users/willian/Desktop/imprimir.py ===============
Localizacao: C:/imprimir
Imprimindo arquivo.. teste - Cópia (2).pdf
Imprimindo arquivo.. teste - Cópia.pdf
Imprimindo arquivo.. teste.pdf
Nenhum arquivo para imprimir 3
>>> 
=============== RESTART: C:/Users/willian/Desktop/imprimir.py ===============
Localizacao: C:/imprimir
Arquivos impressos: 0
>>>
```

Como poderia mandar imprimir e se possível imprimir e mover ou excluir o arquivo?

Comment: Relacionado, mas não duplicado:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65072/como-imprimir-um-arquivo-txt-em-python/65122#65122

Comment: @jsbueno no caso seu está para abrir no navegador e a pessoa ter que dar o comando.. neste caso não fica viável porque esta forma que preciso irão colocar muita coisa na pasta

Answer (score 2):

Os seus arquivos já estão em PDF - é a grande diferença para a resposta em [Como imprimir um arquivo txt em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65072/como-imprimir-um-arquivo-txt-em-python/65122#65122). mas ela dá um bom embasamento do que está envolvido na impressão e por que o Python ou outras linguagens não tem um comando direto para "imprimir".

Mas o link que está naquela resposta para windows (http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) tem, no último exemplo, como imprimir um arquivo PDF no Windows direto a partir do Python:

você deve instalar a win32api (está no Pypi com o nome de `pywin32` - `pip install pywin32` deve ser o suficiente).
E em seguida a chamada na ultima linha no último exemplo no link acima, 
deve ser o suficiente para desencadear a impressão em si:

```
win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", pdf_file_name, None, ".", 0)
```

Se o restante do seu programa estiver ok, pode ser que isso aqui seja o suficiente:

```
import os
import win32api
import pathlib

...     
loc = input('Localizacao: ')

#localizar pasta
floc = pathlib.Path(loc)

#Verifica todos arquivos .pdf que tem na pasta
try:
    os.mkdir(floc/"impressos")
except OSError:
    # pasta já existe
    pass 
for file in glob.glob(floc/'*.pdf'):
    if(file != ''):
        os.startfile(file, 'print')
        print('Imprimindo arquivo.. ' + str(file))
        win32api.ShellExecute (0, "print", os.path.join(floc, file), None, ".", 0)
        x += 1
        time.sleep(2)
        os.rename(floc/file, floc/"impressos"/file)
```

Se o win32api para imprimir falhar, o caminho que eu tentaria aí é  é instalar o ghostview - http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/ - em seguida experimentar e ver a documentação até encontrar uam forma para imprimir com o ghostview a partir de uma linha de comando - e aí usar o o módulo `subprocess` do Python para chamar o ghostview com a linha de comando para imprimir cada arquivo.

(uma dica a parte: evitar usar o `os.chdir` e esperar que as coisas funcionem depois - o ideal é sempre concatenar o nome da pasta ao do arquivo antes de cada operação com arquivos: em scripts pequenos não tem tanto problema - mas em sistemas maiores o "current work dir" é global para a aplicação, em todas as threads e é muito pouco confiável. )
(Se a pathlib não funcionar por conta da sua versão do Python, use os.join.path acima)

Uma outra dica legal aí: No Windows, aplicações de terminal são extremamente desconfortáveis. O Python já vem com ferramentas para criar aplicações gráficas que são bem simples de usar - o que dá trabalho realmente é construir uma aplicação mais sofisticada.
Mas nesse caso, você só precisa de uma pasta, e ficar monitorando a mesma para ver se aparecem mais arquivos - em caso positivo, disparar a impressão.  Criar o app inteiro não posso - mas experimente aí, em vez do input usar isso:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

loc = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

Você pode por o o laço que verifica arquivos no seu script numa função, e chamar essa função com o método `after` da sua janela a cada dois segundos, por exemplo - dessa forma qualquer arquivo colocado lá vai ser impresso.

Apesar da maior parte dos tutorias criar uma classe que herda de tkinter.frame, isso não é necessário: seu programa pode estar numa função normalizinha e simplesmente chamar tkinter.Tk() para ter uma janela.

A estrutura ficaria mais ou menos

```
<importacoes>

pasta = ""

def principal():
    global pasta, janela
    janela = Tkinter.Tk()
    # criar Labels para conter o nome da pasta, mensagens de impressao
    ...
    botao = tkinter.Button(janela, text="Mudar pasta...", command="seleciona_pasta")
    # chama a funcao imprime em 2 segundos:
    janela.after(2000, imprime)

def imprime():
    # basicamente o mesmo código que está na versão de terminal
    # sem o input - a pasta vem na variável global "pasta"
    ...
    # se chama de volta (opcional)
    janela.after(2000, imprime)

def mudar_pasta():
    global pasta
    pasta = filedialog.askdirectory()
    # atualizar label com o nome da pasta atual. 

principal()
```