# Como imprimir PDF'S com python verificando se a impressão foi bem sucedida?

Tags: python, windows, pdf

Existe alguma forma de implementar uma rotina de impressão com python onde seja possível verificar se o arquivo foi impresso com sucesso?
Já tentei utilizar o java com o PDFBOX, mas não encontrei uma forma de fazer essa verificação.
Existe alguma outra biblioteca que forneça essa funcionalidade?

Comment: Não há uma forma única. PDFs são mais simples do que txt - mas dê uma olhada na minha resposta aqui pra ter uma ideia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65072/como-imprimir-um-arquivo-txt-em-python/65122#65122

Comment: minha necessidade é imprimir sem intervenção do usuário @jsbueno

Comment: Preciso saber o sistema operacional para dar mais dicas. Windows?

Comment: Sim, Windows...

Answer (score 3):

Conforme está na minha resposta em [Como imprimir um arquivo txt em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65072/como-imprimir-um-arquivo-txt-em-python/65122#65122) , impressão não é uma característica de nenhuma linguagem, e sim, depende de interação com o sistema operacional.

Acho que um bom caminho, independente do sistema, pode ser usar o Python para chamar o "ghostscript" em um sub-processo: ele pode renderizar o PDF para a API do Windows ou diretamente para a impressora.

A verificação de "se a impressão deu erro", depende do driver de impressão - e aí é necessário mesmo falar com a API do sistema operacional. 
Fiz uma busca rápida e felizmente parece que alguém encapsulou as principais funcionalidades da API do Windows num módulo de Python "win32print" - de uma olhada aqui: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print.html

Com isso daria para usar o [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com) para renderizar o PDF para dados imprimíveis pelo Windows (esqueci o nome do formato interno agora), e usar esse win32print para enviar esses dados resultantes para a impressora. Alguns modelos de impressora podem aceitar arquivos PDF diretamente (é difícil saber nos dias de hoje, já que a pilha de impressão do sistema operacional gerencia tudo), se for o caso, a sua solução pode funcionar sem a parte do ghostscript - só com o win32print.

As outras formas de impressão - usando bibliotecas que tem wrappers em cima da Win32API, tal como gtk+ e Qt, iriam exigir interação com o usuário (elas vão abrir o diálogo padrão de impressão do windows em algum ponto). Também é possível combinar isso com o [Pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) para pressionar os botões de "iniciar impressão" automaticamente - mas seria mais indicado apenas se o seu software já fosse de desktop (e não deixa de ser uma gambiarra).

Infelizmente não há uma resposta curta e simples - vai ser necessária bastante dedicação té funcionar o que você precisa. Se decidir segur por um dos caminhos que indiquei e começar a fazer algum código, fique a vontade para fazer outras perguntas.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda